# Create 6 boxes with css

Tags: css

I really need some help with some easy css that I just can't get my head around.

I want to create boxes like in the link below.
I guess I could have the code for just one of them, and then use it over and over again, but how do I create the boxes so that they don't mind the other stuff around them?

Example here: http://s23.postimg.org/qypbfvv0r/boxes.jpg

[image]

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/acd16hym/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: I have figured out a way of doing this. I hope that this helps you in some way in helping you figure out how to finish your task.

HTML:

```
<div class="containers">
        <p class="heading">Heading</p>
        <div class="inner1"></div>
        <div class="inner2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="containers">
        <p class="heading">Heading</p>
        <div class="inner1"></div>
        <div class="inner2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="containers">
        <p class="heading">Heading</p>
        <div class="inner1"></div>
        <div class="inner2"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.containers {
            width: 300px;
            height: 150px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        .inner1 {
            margin-left: 5px;
            width: 135px;
            height: 80px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .inner2 {
            position: relative;
            float: right;
            top: -60%;
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            width: 135px;
            height: 80px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: red;
        }

        .heading {
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that wordked nicely... just a few things to add to get it to look the way I want to

Comment: I am happy that I could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can start off using this code. After this you can give border styles and colors to the individual divs.

```
<div>
<div style="float:right"> Content </div>
<div style="float:left"> Content </div>
</div>

<div style="padding-top:10px">
<div style="float:right"> Content </div>
<div style="float:left"> Content </div>
</div>

<div style="padding-top:10px">
<div style="float:right"> Content </div>
<div style="float:left"> Content </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps